# Need progress indicator for Tiny Circle Slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am trying to implement tiny circular slider which works fine, but what I want it to show a progress while I slide. Like a progress circular bar(pie). See the screenshot:

[image]

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Pth/).

```
img {
border: 0;
}

/* Tiny Circleslider */
#rotatescroll {
height: 300px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
}

#rotatescroll.viewport {
height: 300px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px}

#rotatescroll.overview {
position: absolute;
width: 798px;
list - style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;}

#rotatescroll.overview li {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
position: relative;}

 #rotatescroll.overlay {
background: url('http://baijs.com/tinycircleslider/images/bg-rotatescroll.png') no - repeat 0 0;
pointer - events: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;}


#rotatescroll.thumb {
background: url('http://baijs.com/tinycircleslider/images/bg-thumb.png') no - repeat 50 % 50 % ;
position: absolute;
top: -3px;
cursor: pointer;
left: 137px;
width: 100px;
z - index: 200;
height: 100px;}

#rotatescroll.dot {
background: url('http://baijs.com/tinycircleslider/images/bg-dot.png') no - repeat 0 0;
display: none;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
position: absolute;
left: 155px;
top: 3px;
z - index: 100;}

#rotatescroll.dot span {
display: none;}

.highlight, .indicator {
    background - color: #FC0;}
```

Comment: just a hint : you got to try in `move` event... `$('#rotatescroll').bind("move", function () {
        console.log("do something on every move to a new slide");   
    });
});`

Comment: Hi Anup sorry for the delay. I did try but with no luck. please tell me what am i doing wrong....this is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A2Pth/2/

Comment: i did this $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rotatescroll').bind("move", function () { 
 console.log("do something on every move to a new slide");
 $indicators.removeClass("highlight");
       $indicators.filter(function( index ) {
           return index < box.slideCurrent;
        }).addClass("highlight");
 
    });
 }); but its not working, what am i doing wrong